# How do i check case sensitivity in where clause

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am doing project in vb.net using ms access database
I used one query like

```
  Command.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT(*) from  CharacterData where Mesg= '" & message & "'"
```

here it is executed when  message variable value is **a** & also if **A**

So how should i make it to check only proper case sensitiviy in where clause ..
I want case sensitive checking of **Mesg= '" & message & "'"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StrComp()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx) or [InStr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/instr.php) ms-access function.

```
str="Select DISTINCT(*) from  CharacterData 
       where InStr(1,Mesg,'" & message & "',0)"
```